# Why did the authors use $\prec$ instead of $\preccurlyeq$ in the definitions of $S_c$ and $S_{c^\ast}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Recently, I have read the proof of theorem 5.3 from textbook *Introduction to Set Theory* by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech.

I would like to know why the authors didn't define $S_c=\{p\in P\mid p \prec c\}$ or $S_{c^\ast}=\{p\in P\mid p \prec^\ast c^\ast\}$. I think that $S_c$ would not necessarily equal to $S_{c^\ast}$ as mentioned in the last line if the authors defined as I mentioned.

> **5.3 Theorem** Let $(P, <)$ be a dense linearly ordered set without endpoints. Then there exists a complete linearly ordered set $(C,\prec)$ such that
>
> (a) $P\subseteq C$.
>
> (b) If $p,q\in P$ then $p < q$ if and only if $p \prec q$ ($<$ coincides with $\prec$ on $P$).
>
> (c) $P$ is dense in $C$, i.e., for any $a,b\in C$ such that $a\prec b$, there is $p\in P$ with $a\prec p \prec b$.
>
> (d) $C$ does not have endpoints.
>
> Moreover, this complete linearly ordered set $(C,\prec)$ is unique up to isomorphism over $P$. In other words, if $(C^\ast,\prec^\ast)$ is a complete linearly ordered set which satisfies (a)-(d), then there is an isomorphism $h$ between $(C,\prec)$ and $(C^\ast,\prec^\ast)$ such that $h(x) = x$ for each $x \in P$. The linearly ordered set $(C,\prec)$ is called the completion of $(P, <)$.
>
> As is usual in theorems of this type, the uniqueness part of the theorem is
>   easier to prove. For that reason, we do it first.
>
> *Proof of Uniqueness of Completion.* Let $(C,\prec)$ and $(C^\ast,\prec^\ast)$ be two complete linearly ordered sets satisfying (a)-(d). We show that there is an isomorphism $h$ of $C$ onto $C^\ast$ such that $h(x)=x$ for each $x\in P$.
>
> If $c\in C$, let $S_c=\{p\in P\mid p \preccurlyeq  c\}$. Similarly, let $S_{c^\ast}=\{p\in P\mid p\preccurlyeq^\ast c^\ast\}$ for $c^\ast\in C^\ast$. If $S$ is a nonempty subset of $P$ bounded from above, let $\sup S$ be the supremum of $S$ in $(C,\prec)$ and $\sup^\ast S$ be the supremum of $S$ in $(C^\ast,\prec^\ast)$. Notice that $\sup S_c=c$, $\sup^\ast S_{c^\ast}=c^\ast$.
>
> We define the mapping $h$ as follows: $h(c)=\sup^\ast S_c$.
>
> Clearl, $h$ is a mapping of $C$ into $C^\ast$; we have to show that the mapping is onto and that
>
> (a) If $c\prec d$, then $h(c)\prec^\ast h(d)$.
>
> (b) $h(x)=x$ for each $x\in P$.
>
> To show that $h$ is onto, let $c^\ast\in C^\ast$ be arbitrary. Then $c^\ast=\sup^\ast S_{c^\ast}$, and if we let $c=\sup S_{c^\ast}$, then $S_c=S_{c^\ast}$ and $c^\ast=h(c)$.

Below is the reasoning for my conclusion. Could you please have a check on my it?

---

1. I would like to verify that $\sup S_c=c$ and $\sup^\ast S_{c^\ast}=c^\ast$.

> Since $S_c=\{p\in P\mid p \preccurlyeq c\}$, $\sup S_c\preccurlyeq c$. If $\sup S_c\prec c$, then there exists $p\in P$ such that $\sup S_c\prec p \prec c$. Thus $p\in S_c$ and $\sup S_c\prec p$. This is clearly a contradiction. Hence $\sup S_c= c$.
>
> Similarly, we can prove that $\sup^\ast S_{c^\ast}=c^\ast$.

2. If we change the definition of $S_c$ to $S_c=\{p\in P\mid p \prec c\}$ and that of $S_{c^\ast}$ to $S_{c^\ast}=\{p\in P\mid p \prec^\ast c^\ast\}$, we still have $\sup S_c=c$ and $\sup^\ast S_{c^\ast}=c^\ast$.

> Since $S_c=\{p\in P\mid p \prec c\}$, $\sup S_c\preccurlyeq c$. If $\sup S_c\prec c$, then there exists $p\in P$ such that $\sup S_c\prec p \prec c$. Thus $p\in S_c$ and $\sup S_c\prec p$. This is clearly a contradiction. Hence $\sup S_c= c$.
>
> Similarly, we can prove that $\sup^\ast S_{c^\ast}=c^\ast$.

3. I would like to verify that $S_c=S_{c^\ast}$ as mentioned in the last line.

> For $c^\ast \in C^\ast$, $S_{c^\ast}=\{p\in P\mid p \preccurlyeq^\ast c^\ast\}$. Let $c=\sup S_{c^\ast}$, then $c\in C$. We have $S_c=\{p\in P\mid p \preccurlyeq c\}$. Notice that $S_{c^\ast} \subseteq P$ and $S_c \subseteq P$.
>
> For any $p\in S_c$, $p \preccurlyeq c$ and thus $p \preccurlyeq \sup S_{c^\ast}$. Then $p \preccurlyeq p'$ for some $p' \in S_{c^\ast}$. If not, $p' \prec p$ for all $p' \in S_{c^\ast}$ and thus $p' \prec p \preccurlyeq \sup S_{c^\ast}$ for all $p' \in S_{c^\ast}$. Then $p=\sup S_{c^\ast}$ and thus $S_c$ has only one element. This clearly contradicts the fact that $P$ does not have a least element. Hence $p \preccurlyeq p'\preccurlyeq^\ast c^\ast$ for some $p' \in S_{c^\ast}$ and consequently $p \preccurlyeq^\ast c^\ast$. Thus $p\in S_{c^\ast}$. To sum up, $p\in S_c \implies p\in S_{c^\ast}$ and thus $S_c\subseteq S_{c^\ast}$.
>
> For any $p\in S_{c^\ast}$, $p \preccurlyeq \sup S_{c^\ast}$ and thus $p \preccurlyeq c$. Then $p\in S_c$. Hence $S_{c^\ast} \subseteq S_c$.
>
> As a result, $S_{c^\ast}=S_{c^\ast}$.

4. I'm quite curious about why the authors didn't define $S_c=\{p\in P\mid p \prec c\}$ or $S_{c^\ast}$ to $S_{c^\ast}=\{p\in P\mid p \prec^\ast c^\ast\}$. I think that $S_c$ would not necessarily equal to $S_{c^\ast}$ as mentioned in the last line if the authors defined as such.

> For example, we instead define $S_c=\{p\in P\mid p \prec c\}$ and keep $S_{c^\ast}=\{p\in P\mid p \preccurlyeq^\ast c^\ast\}$. I found that the first reasoning in 3. is still applicable here. Thus $S_c\subseteq S_{c^\ast}$. But the second reasoning falls apart because: $p \preccurlyeq \sup S_{c^\ast}=c$, but $p$ is not necessarily strictly less than $c$. Hence $p$ does not necessarily belong to $S_c$ and consequently $S_{c^\ast}$ is not necessarily a subset of $S_c$. To sum up, $S_{c^\ast}$ is not necessarily equal to $S_c$.
>
> Similarly, we instead define $S_c=\{p\in P\mid p \prec c\}$ and $S_{c^\ast}=\{p\in P\mid p \prec^\ast c^\ast\}$. Then $S_{c^\ast}$ is not necessarily equal to $S_c$.

Comment: Since I'm newbie to MSE, I'm unable to fetch images directly in my post. I'm very sorry for this inconvenience! Please click on the links to view images!

Comment: I have edited your post to display the pictures. Trick: add an exclamation point in front of each line of pictures. This is actually the syntax of Markdown. You may search on the Internet for details.

Comment: Thank you so much @xbh! Your trick is very useful :)

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I have typed out all the relevant quotes from the textbook as you suggested and added them to my post. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think you are correct that both definitions work. It's just like the sup of $(0, 1)$ is the same as the sup of $(0, 1]$. So it doesn't matter whether you include the right endpoint or not so long as the orders involved are dense.

Comment: @Y.Ding Please address 4. why the authors did not define $S_c$ as $S_c=\{p\in P\mid p \prec c\}$ and $S_{c^\ast}$ as $S_{c^\ast}=\{p\in P\mid p \prec^\ast c^\ast\}$. i.e. the authors did not define $S_c$ and $S_{c^\ast}$ by strict order $\prec,\prec^\ast$, but by $\preccurlyeq,\preccurlyeq^\ast$.

Comment: My point is that both would work: either define $S_{c^*}$ and $S_{c}$ both by strict orders or both by weak orders. You seem to be concerned by the possibility that if we use just strict orders, we might have $S_c \not= S_{c^*}$ where $c = \sup S_{c^*}$. But I think you can show that they are indeed equal. One idea is start by discussing two cases: $c^* \in P$ and $c^* \in C^* \setminus P$. In the former case, $c$ will be the same as $c^*$. In the latter case, we can first show that $c$ is also in $C \setminus P$ and then proceed to show that $S_c = S_{c^*}$.

Comment: Hi @Y.Ding! I seem to find a proof that $S_{c^*}=S_c$ in case of strict orders. Please have a check on it!

Comment: @Y.Ding [...] For $c^*\in C^*, S_{c^*}=\{p\in P\mid p\prec^* c^*\}$. Let $c=\sup S_{c^*}$, then $c\in C$ and $S_c=\{p\in P\mid p\prec c\}$. For $p\in S_{c^*},p \preccurlyeq \sup S_{c^*}$ and thus $p \preccurlyeq c$. I claim that $p\in S_{c^*} \implies p\prec c$.

Comment: @Y.Ding [...] If not, there exists $p'\in S_{c^*}$ such that $p'=c$. Furthermore, $p'\prec^* c^*$ by the fact that $p'\in S_{c^*}$. Since $P$ is dense in $C^*$, there exists $p''\in P$ such that $p'\prec^* p'' \prec^* c^*$. Thus $p'=c=\sup S_{c^*}\prec^* p'' \prec^* c^*$ and $p',p''\in S_{c^*}$. This clearly contradicts the fact that $c$ is the supremum of $S_{c^*}$. Hence $p\in S_{c^*} \implies p\prec c \implies p\in S_c$. Thus $S_{c^*} \subseteq S_c$.